# COUNTIFS based on date ranges criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

Trying to count the number of tier levels (tier 1-3) for each month of the year.

Heres the logic I'm trying formulate:

IF (E9:E >=1/1/2023, E9:E <=1/31/2023, COUNTA(E9:E = "1"))

I feel like the answer might be hidden with COUNTIFS somewhere in it, but nothing I've done to this point has worked.

Thanks,

Comment: LOL. Got it. 

COUNTIFS(E9:E, "1",F9:F >=1/1/2023, F9:F <=1/31/2023)

Apparently you need to go in order of the columns you're querying.

Comment: If you answered your own question you should post an answer so that when you look it up years later you can find the solution.

Comment: Good looking out, @CodeCamper

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

COUNTIFS(E9:E, "1",F9:F >=1/1/2023, F9:F <=1/31/2023)

Apparently you need input criteria in left to right order of the columns you're querying.